# Running ROS in a Tensorflow virtual environment

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run Tensorflow in a virtual environment and I want to run a python node in this virtual environment. I'm getting an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

I've tried running `source ./devel/setup.bash` but that didn't help solve the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285483/running-ros-in-a-tensorflow-virtual-environment/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-03-18**:
Hi pleas see this question https://answers.ros.org/question/228940/integrating-tensorflow-into-ros/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the reply.
Turns out that I needed to pip install rospkg catkin_pkg

---

Originally posted by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) with karma: 115 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1